# Only one location in coordinate array showing up on map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have the following code which I expect to drop 3 points on my leaflet map. Oddly it only displays the 3rd value in the array. No errors logging to the console. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

````
        var cities = ["Victoria", "Bettles", "Truth or Consequences"]; // cities to map

        // variable to hold number value of city population
        var cityPops = [92141, 13, 5948];

        // 2-D array of corresponding city coordinates -- getting this error here. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null". Only way I can get the marker to load is as a single point, not as a 2D array
        var cityCoords = [
          [48.430077, -123.353043],
          [66.905857, -151.533330],
          [33.1284, -107.25283]
        ];
        console.log(cityCoords);

        // boolean indicating whether the city is a capital or not
        var cityCapital = [true, false, false];
        // for loop with if statement indicating whether city s a capital or not
        for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
          var cityName = cities[i];
          console.log(cityName)
          var cityPop = cityPops[i];
          console.log(cityPop)
          var cityCap = cityCapital[i];
          console.log(cityCap)
          var cityCoord = cityCoords[i];
          console.log(cityCoord)
          var nameAndPop = `<b>${cityName}</b><b>population:</b> ${cityPop}`;

          if (cityCap == true) {
            console.log(nameAndPop)
            console.log(cityCap, `is a capital city`);
          }
        }
        // build a string with HTML tags and content
        var popup = `<b>${cityName}</b><br>
                    <b>population</b>: ${cityPop}<br>`
        { cityCap } `is a capital city`
        console.log(popup)

        // create a Leaflet marker
        // add it to the map
        // and bind the popup content to the marker.
        L.marker(cityCoord).addTo(map)
          .bindPopup(popup);```
````

Comment: What does your console output look like?

Comment: Run the `L.marker` in the loop. Unless, there is something I'm not seeing everything after and including `var popup` is outside the loop. That's not what you want.

Comment: Yay! L.marker in the loop looks like it worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

1. You do a loop
2. putting current values into `cityName`, `cityPop` etc
3. your loop is over
4. `cityName`, `cityPop` etc are having a values of the last array item
5. you are working with a `popup` just once.

Does it makes sense?

Answer: put your `var popup =...`and other building logic **inside** the loop to make it work as many times as many items you have in array

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
        var cityName = cities[i];
        console.log(cityName)
        var cityPop = cityPops[i];
        console.log(cityPop)
        var cityCap = cityCapital[i];
        console.log(cityCap)
        var cityCoord = cityCoords[i];
        console.log(cityCoord)
        var nameAndPop = `<b>${cityName}</b><b>population:</b> ${cityPop}`;
        var popup = `<b>${cityName}</b><br>
                    <b>population</b>: ${cityPop}<br>`
                    {cityCap} `is a capital city`
        if (cityCap == true) {
          console.log(nameAndPop)
          console.log(cityCap, `is a capital city`);
        }
}
```